# How do i link state provider with my custom signin function to retrive get username

Tags: flutter, dart, state, provider

I was trying to retrieve user details from signin function so that I can use it on other screens in the flutter app but it seems it does not work as expected using Provider as state manager.

```
 void LoginFunction() {
if (username.text.isEmpty) {
  scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(
      mySnackBar("Provide username")
  );
} else if (password.text.isEmpty) {
  scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(
      mySnackBar("Provide Password")
  );
} else {
  print(username.text);
  print(password.text);

  Provider.of<SignInDetailsModel>(context, listen: false).signIn(username.text, password.text);
}}
```

but if I do not use the . combination in the provider then the signup works but the provider does not work. Any ideas on how to solve it the PHP webserver scripts work perfectly. If anyone has any ideas on how to use any other state management I would appreciate it

```
class SignInDetailsModel with ChangeNotifier {  String Username = ""; String Userpass =""; void signIn(String userName, String password) {
Username = userName;
Userpass = password;
print("The logged in user is ${Username}");
notifyListeners();}}




  signIn(String username, String password) async {
DialogBuilder(context).showLoadingIndicator(
    "Please wait as we authenticate you", "Authentication");
Map data = {'username': username, 'password': password};
var jsonResponse;
var response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse("php script "),
    body: data);
print("\n ${response.body} \n");

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  print(response.body);
  if (jsonResponse != null) {
    setState(() {
      DialogBuilder(context).hideOpenDialog();
    });
    int isRegistered = jsonResponse['code'];
    if (isRegistered == 1) { //correct password


      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeNav()));
    } else {
      scaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar(
        mySnackBar("Wrong Password"),
      );
    }
  }
} else {
  setState(() {
    DialogBuilder(context).hideOpenDialog();
  });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

General ideal to use textcontroller text via Provider

```
class ModelClass extend ChangeNotifier{
  TextEditingController textEditingController= TextEditingController();
   
}
```

/// your class where you have textfeild and ChangeNotifierProvider/consumer

```
   TextFeild(
    controller: model.textEditingController;
)
```

/// Where you want to use the textfeild value or Consumer class

```
   Text(model.textEditingController.text);
```

For complete example of how to user textfeild controller in another screen via Provider follow the link

https://github.com/navidanchitrali/todoApp-